# SQL to retrieve cancelled services without new stamps

Tags: sql, oracle

I have vehicles inside a services table, that first get a stamp and them an essay, stamp and essay are linked steps inside the services tables.

First came a stamp and second came an essay.

After all they get a certificate linked to the essay from the services table.

I need to retrieve only canceled certificates (status = 0 ) that do not have any new service with new stamps after the canceled essay .

My query is :

```
SELECT 
    cert.essay_id,
    cert.status, 
    ser.essay_id,
    ser.stamp_id,
    ser.created,
    v.ds_plate
FROM vehicles v
JOIN services ser ON ser.vei_id = v.vei_id
LEFT JOIN certificates cert ON cert.essay_id = ser.essay_id AND cert.status = 0
WHERE v.ds_plate = 'ABC1234' ORDER BY ser.created DESC;
```

And the results i have are :

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  ESSAY_ID |  STATUS  | ESSAY_ID  | STAMP_ID  | CREATED               | DS_PLATE
1|           |          |           | 4303333   | 10/07/2017 15:54:05   | ABC1234
2|  4254441  |  0       | 4254441   |           | 20/12/2016 16:52:05   | ABC1234
3|           |          |           | 4263152   | 20/12/2016 16:42:51   | ABC1234
```

In a minimalistic way these are the tables involved:

### vehicles

vei_id
ds_plate

### services

vei_id
essay_id
stamp_id
created

### certificates

id
essay_id 
status
created

### I would like to find only these situations, when no new stamp was added after having a essay_id linked to an certificate and with status = 0 inside the services table :

```
 |  ESSAY_ID |  STATUS  | ESSAY_ID  | STAMP_ID  | CREATED               | DS_PLATE

1|  4254441  |  0       | 4254441   |           | 20/12/2016 16:52:05   | ABC1234
2|           |          |           | 4263152   | 20/12/2016 16:42:51   | ABC1234
```

Comment: please post some sample data.

Comment: Need your table structures. Not sure how we can determine your expected output without it. "I need to retrieve only canceled certificates the do not have any new service with new stamps after the canceled essay ."

Comment: can you share excepted output?

Comment: Do you want only first row according to your results ? @Ângelo Rigo

Comment: I think i need a join to exclude vehicles that have that first line of the example for the vehicle ABC1234 wich brings a stamp greater than 4263152   the preceding stamp of the essay 4254441

Comment: first came a stamp and them an essay a stamp created after the canceled essay would be a new pair for a new essay

Comment: So, do you want  to like this  output? ==>> " 4254441 | 0 | 4254441 | 4263152 | 20/12/2016 16:42:51 | ABC1234 " @Ângelo Rigo

Comment: @OP, you will need to define your table. It's hard to determine what a **" canceled certificates the do not have any new service with new stamps after the canceled essay"** is if your table doesn't show any of us what these mean

Comment: the stamp_id is the first step, inside a services table,  and linked to it i have a essay_id

Comment: if the essay_id linked to certificates have status = 0 i want to retrieve only vehicles that do not have a new stamp after the essay_id canceled inside the certificate.